# Using Angular's "as" without *ngIf?

Tags: angular

If I have some Observable `data$`, I can use `as` in Angular as follows:

```
<ng-template #loading>Loading...</ng-template>
<ng-container *ngIf="(data$ | async) as data; else loading">
  <div *ngFor="let item of data">...</div>
</ng-container>
```

That's really cool and useful as it avoids subscribing to `data$` more than once. However, what if I want to avoid doing so but stay within the same container? Ideally, something like (the obviously not working)

```
<ng-container let-data="data$ | async">
  <ng-container *ngIf="!data">Loading</ng-container>
  <!-- ... -->
</ng-container>
```

or

```
<ng-container *let="(data$ | async) as data">
  <ng-container *ngIf="!data">Loading</ng-container>
  <!-- ... -->
</ng-container>
```

In other words, I want to make use of the `as` binding to avoid multiple subscriptions, but I don't actually want to render that container conditionally.

Is this possible? It feels like there should be an easy answer that I'm missing. :-)

---

On a side note, of course I know that I could just do

```
data$.takeUntil(this.destroy$).subscribe(data => this.data = data);
```

in my component class, but I'm wondering whether there's a way to avoid this and handle it in the template directly.

Comment: @estus The accepted answer in that thread mentions exactly what I started my question with, so IMHO it's not a duplicate.

Comment: There's more than one answer in this question, and another one addresses your case specifically.

Comment: Ah, I see. Indeed, appears to be a duplicate now.

Comment: Please search for answers before posting!

Comment: @user1247395 You don't have to go on hate sprees because I voted to close one of your questions.

Comment: comes up first in google for me...  solution appears:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15280

Comment: @KenF weird you call it a solution when the ticket you linked to is still open...more than 2 years later, might I add...